# Multply (or divide) dividend and divisor in integer division

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

I have a question about the integer (Euclidean) division.
It seems to me that in the case of integer division it is not possible to multiply (or divide) both members by the same number (equivalence principle).

In fact, for example, $\frac{19}{5}=3  \quad (rem = 4) $, while $\frac{-19}{-5}=4 \quad (rem= 1)$ .

How can this behavior be explained?

Thank you all

Carlo

Answer (score 0):

Very briefly, it is because $15\leq19<20$ but $-20\leq-19<-15$.

Euclidean division $\frac ab$ cares about the largest multiple of $b$ which is no greater than $a$. In the case of $\frac{19}5$ that's $15$, and in the case of $\frac{-19}{-5}$, that's $-20$.

Note that multiplying above and below by the same *positive* integer does not change the result of the division, although the remainder will grow by that same factor.

Comment: Yes, but multiplying above and below by  -1 really change the result of the division. Put in other words, in Euclidean division, seems that you cannot simplify the minus signs, because this would change the result of the division. Tks.